# JList Multiple Component

Tags: string, image, jlist

I want to make a chat client which can send text and images.

I have this jlist  for handling text and image output.

I'm using vector to add elements when I add image to jlist it adds successfully, but when I try to add text it does not

Here is the code:

```
Vector<Object> model;
JScrollPane sp1;
JList p1;
public gui1()
{
   super("Chat1");
   model=new Vector<Object>();
   p1=new JList();
   sp1=new JScrollPane(p1);
}

adding image is good

model.add(ll1.getSelectedValue());//ll1.getSelectValue() gets the path of image
p1.setListData(model);//ll1 is another jlist with multiple images

but when i try adding string

String msg=din.readUTF();
model.add(msg);
p1.setListData(model);

it shows exception => java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Chat1 : message"
```